# Why I get 'statement or delimiter expected, got ...' error for @Table annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

I just started learning spring boot but I keep running into this error shown below when I set the name in the @Table annotation. I have absolutely no idea what is causing it since I do have the table defined in my schema. My at column annotations seem to work fine so it at least recognizes to columns of the table. Any advice? Thanks.

[image: This is a screenshot showing the issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having some SQL dialect injected into this string. Un-inject the language from Alt+Enter [Intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html) popup menu:

[image]

Now, to make this table annotation be resolved into a database table - you should [assign](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#assign_data_source) a [data source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-database-connections.html) to your JPA persistence unit in Persistence tool window:

[image]
[image]

then navigation will work:

[image]